# How to search for multiple data from multiple lines and store them in dictionary?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, dictionary

Say I have a file with the following:

```
/* Full name: abc */
.....
.....(.....)
.....(".....) ;
/* .....
/* .....
..... : "....."
}
"....., .....
Car : true ;
House : true ;
....
....
Age : 33
....
/* Full name: xyz */
....
....
Car : true ;
....
....
Age : 56
....
```

I am only interested in full name, car, house and age of each person. There are many other lines of data with different format between the variable/attritbute that I am interested.

My code so far:

```
import re

initial_val = {'House': 'false', 'Car': 'false'}

with open('input.txt') as f:
    records = []
    current_record = None
    for line in f:
        if not line.strip():
            continue
        elif current_record is None:
            people_name = re.search('.+Full name ?: (.+) ', line)
            if people_name:
                current_record = dict(initial_val, Name = people_name.group(1))
            else:
                continue
        elif current_record is not None:
            house = re.search(' *(House) ?: ?([a-z]+)', line)
            if house:
                current_record['House'] = house.group(2)
            car = re.search(' *(Car) ?: ?([a-z]+)', line)
            if car:
                current_record['Car'] = car.group(2)
            people_name = re.search('.+Full name ?: (.+) ', line)
            if people_name:
                records.append(current_record)
                current_record = dict(initial_val, Name = people_name.group(1))                       

print records
```

What I get:

```
[{'Name': 'abc', 'House': 'true', 'Car': 'true'}]
```

My question:

How am I suppose to extract the data and store it in a dictionary like:

```
{'abc': {'Car': true, 'House': true, 'Age': 33}, 'xyz':{'Car': true, 'House': false, 'Age': 56}}
```

My purpose:

check whether each person has car, house and age, if no then return false

The I could print them in a table like this:

```
Name Car House Age
abc true true 33
xyz true false 56
```

Note that I am using Python 2.7 and I do not know what is the actual value of each variable/attribute (Eg. abc, true, true, 33) of each person.

What is the best solution to my question? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you just have to keep track of the current record:

```
def parse_name(line):
    # first remove the initial '/* ' and final ' */'
    stripped_line = line.strip('/* ')
    return stripped_line.split(':')[-1]


WANTED_KEYS = ('Car', 'Age', 'House')

# default values for when the lines are not present for a record
INITIAL_VAL = {'Car': False, 'House': False, Age: -1}

with open('the_filename') as f:
    records = []
    current_record = None

    for line in f:
        if not line.strip():
             # skip empty lines
             continue
        elif current_record is None:
             # first record in the file
             if line.startswith('/*'):
                 current_record = dict(INITIAL_VAL, name=parse_name(line))
             else:
                 # this should probably be an error in the file contents
                 continue
        elif line.startswith('/*'):
            # this means that the current record finished, and a new one is starting
            records.append(current_record)
            current_record = dict(INITIAL_VAL, name=parse_name(line))
        else:
            key, val = line.split(':')
            if key.strip() in WANTED_KEYS:
                # we want to keep track of this field
                current_record[key.strip()] = val.strip()
            # otherwise just ignore the line


print('Name\tCar\tHouse\tAge')
for record in records:
    print(record['name'], record['Car'], record['House'], record['Age'], sep='\t')
```

Note that for `Age` you may want to convert it to an integer using `int`:

```
if key == 'Age':
    current_record['Age'] = int(val)
```

The above code produces a list of dictionaries, but it is easy enough to convert it to a dictionary of dicts:

```
new_records = {r['name']: dict(r) for r in records}
for val in new_records.values():
    del val['name']
```

After this `new_records` will be something like:

```
{'abc': {'Car': True, 'House': True, Age: 20}, ...}
```

---

If you have other lines with a different format in between the interesting ones you can simply write a function that returns `True` or `False` depending on whether the line is in the format you require and use it to `filter` the lines of the file:

```
def is_interesting_line(line):
    if line.startswith('/*'):
        return True
    elif ':' in line:
        return True

for line in filter(is_interesting_line, f):
    # code as before
```

Change `is_interesting_line` to suit your needs. In the end, if you have to handle several different formats etc. maybe using a regex would be better, in that case you could do something like:

```
import re

LINE_REGEX = re.compile(r'(/\*.*\*/)|(\w+\s*:.*)| <other stuff>')

def is_interesting_line(line):
    return LINE_REGEX.match(line) is not None
```

---

If you want you can obtain fancier formatting for the table, but you probably first need to determine the maximum length of the name etc. or you can use something like [`tabulate`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) to do that for you.

For example something like (not tested):

```
max_name_length = max(max(len(r['name']) for r in records), 4)
format_string = '{:<{}}\t{:<{}}\t{}\t{}'
    print(format_string.format('Name', max_name_length, 'Car', 5,  'House', 'Age'))
    for record in records:
        print(format_string.format(record['name'], max_name_length, record['Car'], 5, record['House'], record['Age']))
```

Comment: I appreciate your help very much. However, in the part where you wrote "key, val = line.split(':')" will not work for me because there are other lines of data between those attribute/variable that is not in the form of (key : value ;), may I know what changes should I make?

Comment: @user3118123 The loop is processing one line at a time. **If** the file is in the format that you described, i.e. lines of the form `something : value` then it should work. Because during one iteration of the loop `line` will be the string `Age: 33` then `line.split(':')` returns the list `['Age', '33']` and so you have that `key = Age` and `val  = 33`.  If this is not the case you should clarify exactly the file format you are dealing with, maybe providing an actual example with fake that but exact formatting.

Comment: sorry for not providing enough info, I have edited the file content. Basically, the file has many lines of different format. Is it better to do this using regex? But I also not sure how to use regex.

Comment: @user3118123 You can simply filter the lines before. Or actually you could just add an `if ':' not in line: continue` before the `line.split(':')`. Edited the answer.

Comment: I have decided to use regex to perform my search. However, I was not getting the output that I want (test for `Name` and `House` only). I have added my code. Could you please help me to modify my code on how to assign `false` to the variable if it is not found and how to store the data in a dictionary so that I want to obtain something like your `new_records`?

Comment: I have refer to your answer and updated my code. I have found out that your code will not append `current_record` of `xyz` to `records` because no next people is detected. Could you please guide me how to solve this problem?

Comment: @user3118123 Oh well, given that you didn't provide a testable document my code is only a guideline, not a complete working solution. In any case I believe you should be fine by just adding a check after the `for` loop and see if `current_record is not None` and if so add it to `records`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Thanks, it works fine. However, I am getting this error `'str' object does not support item deletion` due to this part `del val['Name']` by using your code for converting a list of dictionaries into a dictionary of dictionaries. May I know what to change?

Comment: @user3118123 Oh yeah. It should be `for val in new_dictionary.values()`. Otherwise it iterates over the keys, which are strings.